# How to create consistent 3D images in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-3dplot

I would like to create images similar to these ones: [image] [image]

However I would like to be able to do so in a coordinate system specific way so that I don't have to think about how the 2D projection of the image relates to the 3D image it is supposed to represent. For example: In the second image, Is there a way to specify a circle of a given radius centred at a particular z coordinate such that when viewed from different angles the circle changes (becomes an ellipse) so that perspective is honoured?

Basically I want to define objects in 3D and let tikz do all the work concerning rotations etc.

Comment: `tikz-3dplot` package has some nice/handy macros, although I'm not sure it's what you want. By the way, it's much more likely that you get help if you post a compilable example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) of the code you already have pointing out what is what you don't know how to do.

Comment: You might want to check out [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) which has built-in facilities for doing this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an attempt. On the first plot, the first quadrant is the same as the second plot, but x-axis and y-axis are labeled interchangeably, then draw the x-axis line on the negative direction. For detail usages of the commands, they can be found in the documentation of [tikz-3dplot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot).

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
% ----- First plot    
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{145}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3, tdplot_main_coords, axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
vector/.style={-stealth,black,very thick},
vector guide/.style={dotted,black,thick},
]

%standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ay}{-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\az}{0.5}

\coordinate (P) at (\ax,\ay,\az){};

%draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};   % x-axis becomes y axis
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,-2,0) node[anchor=south]{$x$}; %minius y-axis becomes positive x axis
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

%draw a vector from O to P
\draw[vector guide] (O) -- (P)node{$\bullet$} node[left](){$(x,y,z)$};

% draw guide lines to components
\draw[vector guide] (O) -- (\ax,\ay,0);
\draw[vector guide] (\ax,\ay,0) -- (P);
\draw[vector guide] (\ax,\ay,0) -- (0,\ay,0);
\draw[vector guide] (\ax,\ay,0) -- (0,\ay,0);
\draw[vector guide] (\ax,\ay,0) -- (\ax,0,0);
\node[tdplot_main_coords,anchor=east]  at (\ax,0,0){};
\node[tdplot_main_coords,anchor=west]  at (0,\ay,0){};

\draw[thick,tdplot_main_coords] (1.5,0.5,0)-- (1.5,-0.5,0) -- (-1.5,-0.5,0)--(-1.5,0.5,0)--cycle;
\node[above] at (-0.6,0.1,0){$\bullet$};
\node at (-1,0,0) {$(x_0,y_0)$};

\draw[tdplot_main_coords,->,>=latex'] (0,2,0)--node[midway,above]{$U$} (0,1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Second plot

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{115}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=3, tdplot_main_coords, axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
vector/.style={-stealth,black,very thick},
vector guide/.style={dashed,black,thick}]

%standard tikz coordinate definition using x, y, z coords
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);

%tikz-3dplot coordinate definition using r, theta, phi coords

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ay}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\az}{1}

\coordinate (P) at (\ax,\ay,\az){};

%draw axes
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$\mathbf{e_x}$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$\mathbf{e_y}$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$\mathbf{e_z}$};

%draw a vector from O to P
\draw[vector] (O) -- (P);% node(){$\bullet$};

\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_main_coords]{(0,0,1)}{1.414}{0}{360}{anchor=north}{}

% draw guide lines to components
\draw[vector guide] (O) -- (\ax,\ay,0);
\draw[vector guide] (\ax,\ay,0) -- (P);
\draw[thick, <-,>=latex']  (P) --node[midway,above]{$r'$} (0,0,\az);
\node[tdplot_main_coords,above,left] at (0,-0.2,\az){$\zeta_3$};

\draw[thick,tdplot_main_coords,->,>=latex'] (1,1,1)-- (1,1,0.5) node[anchor=west]{$F_T$};
\draw[thick,tdplot_main_coords,->,>=latex'] (1,1,1)-- (1.5,0.8,1) node[anchor=east]{$F_D$};
\draw[thick,tdplot_main_coords,->,>=latex'] (1,1,1)
-- (1.5,1.5,1) node[anchor=south]{$F_R$};

\draw[dashed,tdplot_main_coords] (0.2,0,1)-- (-0.2,0,1);
\draw[dashed,tdplot_main_coords] (0,0.2,1)-- (0,-0.2,1);

\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_main_coords,color=blue,->]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}%
{45}{anchor=north,color=black}{$\Omega t+\phi'$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the second tikz picture from your code does not run in my TexStudio due to the line "\draw[thick, <-,>=latex']  (P) --node[midway,above]{$r\rq{}$} (0,0,\az)" Any ideas what that could be?

Comment: OK, I saw the problem, change \rq{} to '. Mine is TexWorks editor.

Comment: Thanks now everything works beautifully, however I think there is a missing ";" on that line mentioned above and I think "latex'" should just be "latex" again in the line mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Ya, not until you mentioned it. My code in PC has it though. Thanks.