# How to draw topological surfaces?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am making some notes on differential geometry and topology lecture. As I know in LaTeX we can draw some very nice images. But I was not able to find any examples on surfaces, which I could use. Is it possible to make this kind of plots?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How can I add stippling to elements of my tikz diagrams?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266881/how-can-i-add-stippling-to-elements-of-my-tikz-diagrams)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192188/how-to-create-consistent-3d-images-in-tikz

Comment: Vaguely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17031/86

Comment: Possible? Yes. Sensible? No. It would be better to use the kind of software which knows about 3D and allows you to rotate objects etc. as that will be much more powerful, flexible and efficient.

Comment: You can use such software in a way which is fully integrated into your documents, though. For example, you can include the code for the plot in your document but have it plotted by an external programme.

Comment: I took the liberty to close it as a duplicate because there are two very close examples in the duplicate question but let us know if you don't agree. Frankly, I don't think it can get any better than that