# How to create graphics for notes of vectorial calculus?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, vector

I'm kinda new in this thing of Latex's Graphics, recently I'm trying to make lecture notes of multivarible calculus, but I'd like to iunclude the geometrical perpective and you better know ain't the best drawer, so I would like to complement it with some beamer-type of presentation.

Okay, too much information..., my real problem is: I still don't know how to "recreate" this kind of graphics to include them in the notes, I had had many problems with Ticks in the past, I'd like to have other options.

Graphics such as:

[image]

or

[image]

Sure any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Welcome! It is certainly possible to recreate these figures, but I am wondering what you already have done and where you got stuck.

Comment: How about you start from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192188/how-to-create-consistent-3d-images-in-tikz) and ask questions if you encounter problems?